# GORM Mapping of BigInteger

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am using Grails 2.1.0 and one of my domain classes needs to store a timestamp (which is a 64-bit unsigned integer).  I know in C++ unsigned long long is appropriate for this but I wasn't sure what to use in Groovy/Grails.  I went with a BigInteger to represent this field in my domain class.

However, I have a legacy app in Java that needs to write to the database generated by the Grails application.  When I run the NetBeans HBM file and POJO generation on the database the setter/getter operations for this timestamp field are BigDecimal rather than BigInteger.  Why is that happening?

I tried converting to BigDecimal but the incoming value will not fit in a DECIMAL(19,2) when it is written to the database.  I did some searching on the Grails forums and someone said this was a problem with Hibernate.  That was several years ago so I was hoping there was a better solution than writing a custom type (which is what was recommended in the post).  I couldn't find anything on the Hibernate forums about the issue either.